# How do you disable the "last accessed" attribute on NTFS/Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, ntfs, hard-drive

Inspired by [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/2287/is-using-2-solid-state-drives-in-raid-0-going-to-be-reliable/33916#33916) answer, I realize I have no idea how to disable the last accessed attribute in Windows to increase performance. If you can, how?

I know in Linux you can mount the partition with the 'noatime' option, but is there a similar feature in Windows for NTFS?

Comment: Oooh, this will be a good one, +1

Comment: I split the difference between Sven's and J Rennie's answers - they both answer the question but provide different information.

Comment: just a comment about the linux "noatime": in many cases it's safer (and almost as efficient) to use "relatime", with linux fs/kernels >2008. relatime will write the atime only if the file was updated since the last atime, or X days/hours passed (default 24h?).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1
```

But be careful, some program (especially backup programs) might need this.

Comment: Accepted -- nice use of fsutil. +1 went to the reg entry and the technet link from J Rennie.

Comment: I don't see why backup programs would use it? I think such software would rely on last modified attribute instead.

Comment: @lucek: I agree that it should but the Windows platform is full of cheap crap made by morons without a clue and unfortunately, "backup" software people use is way too often the ultra-cheap crap from the last corner of India or China that is preloaded onto equally cheap external disks or thumb drives they use for backup purposes. Since I don't trust that this stuff gets the basics done right, I wrote the warning that it *might* have side effects to turn these attributes off.

Comment: Is this still working on Windows 10?

Comment: Note that it's not just bad programs that use it: MS's own [AgeStore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-agestore) tool for removing old .pdb debug symbols from, e.g., your local cache uses it, too, which can cause issues since Vista switched the default.

Answer (score 9):

The `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate` ([docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959914.aspx)) registry entry is a `REG_DWORD` that can be:

- `0`: update the last-access timestamp, and record each change in the NTFS log (default)
- `1`: don't update the last-access timestamp, and don't record time stamp updates in the NTFS log

Whether it makes much difference is debatable.

JR

Comment: +1 for the registry entry and technet link -- I was rather torn as to which would be 'better', but wanted to promote the use of fsutil.

Comment: I did this before plugging in a cheap USB2 flash drive that is formatted in NTFS with lots of files. The read performance increase is HUGE! Thank you. I also created .reg files on my desktop to turn the feature on and off.